# IIS 7.5 Error Could not find file 'con.asp' when switching to “Content View” [Image Attached]

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis

When changing from features view to content view I get the following error "Could not find file 'con.asp'.", shown below

[image: IIS Error switching to Content View]

There's never been a con.asp in the folder as for as I'm aware and generally if it was something missing in the folder it doesn't normally kick off an error. Making me believe it's actually something in a config file or something. I've checked the web.config file for any reference but nothing to be found. Hoping this is quite a common issue for people that troubleshoot IIS often.

Comment: This happens on all sites in IIS? Sounds very whack.

Comment: No just that one. It's very confusing indeed

Comment: The "Content View" also comes up blank after that as well.